# Cognos render variable roll up measures

Tags: variables, aggregation, cognos

I have a requirement for a dynamic report where the user can select what columns they want to display. This is not a problem for me to do using render variable, however, the measures are not rolling up.

As an example, I have age, gender and sales. This generates say, age 20 and 25, and obviously 2 genders, resulting in 4 rows.

When you remove gender using the static choices in the prompt page, it keeps 4 rows, just without displaying the age. I understand this is the nature of 'rendering' (or not) the column.

What I need is for the measures to roll up to what columns are left, which would show 2 rows, and a total. Or even remove all columns, and have just an overall total sales left.

I cant really use conditional blocks to create every combination as there is going to be 20+ columns in the report.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Change you conditionally rendered field to something like

```
case when ?render_gender? then [Gender] else '' end
```

This should zip your four rows to two.

Comment: That works when only selecting a single column, but I need to be able to select a range of columns in the prompt page

Comment: Got it! using what you had suggested, but use something like the following: case when 'gender' in ?render_gender then [gender] end

Comment: Yes. It depends on your prompts